# Dual displays not working, white backgorund

Tags: 12.10, multiple-monitors

My problem is that my second display is white. The things I've tried is: System settings > Displays > enable display. Then I get: required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3840, 1200), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1920, 1920)

I downloaded the latest driver and CCC. Then I tried to use Catalyst Control Center and enabling the display there, then where I got the white display after rebooting.

This is how my driver looks like:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cayman XT [Radeon HD 6970]
```

This is how my X11 xorg.conf look like:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "amdcccle Layout"
    Screen      0  "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0" 0 0
    Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1" 1920 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP9"
    Option       "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option       "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option       "DPMS" "true"
    Option       "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option       "Position" "0 0"
    Option       "Rotate" "normal"
    Option       "Disable" "false"
    Option       "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP11"
    Option       "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option       "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option       "DPMS" "true"
    Option       "PreferredMode" "1920x1200"
    Option       "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option       "Position" "0 0"
    Option       "Rotate" "normal"
    Option       "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP9" "0-DFP9"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP11" "0-DFP11"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth     24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success solving a similar problem in the past doing the following.  First unplug the second display and run:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

This will reinitialize your xorg.conf.  Now reboot your machine.  After the reboot, plug the second display back in, run

```
gksu amdcccle
```

and configure the displays how you like.  Note that if you run the Catalyst Control Center from the dash, it won't have root permissions and won't be able to save your configuration to xorg.conf.